# How do I know what file have been downloaded in the completed event?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private async void BtnDownloadFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnDownloadFile.IsEnabled = false; // Disable to prevent multiple runs

            using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36");

                wc.DownloadProgressChanged += OnDownloadProgressChange;
                wc.DownloadFileCompleted += OnDownloadFileComplete;

                stopwatch.Start();
                await DownloadAsync(wc);
            }
        }

        private void OnDownloadProgressChange(object sender, System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Calculate progress values
            string downloadProgress = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
            string downloadSpeed = string.Format("{0} MB/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));
            string downloadedMBs = Math.Round(e.BytesReceived / 1024.0 / 1024.0) + " MB";
            string totalMBs = Math.Round(e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024.0 / 1024.0) + " MB";
            
            // Format progress string
            string progress = $"{downloadedMBs}/{totalMBs} ({downloadProgress}) @ {downloadSpeed}"; // 10 MB / 100 MB (10%) @ 1.23 MB/s

            // Set values to contols
            lblProgress.Content = progress;
            progBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        private async void OnDownloadFileComplete(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            lblProgress.Content = "Download complete!";
            stopwatch.Reset();
            btnDownloadFile.IsEnabled = true;

            if(e.Error == null)
            {
                urlsCounter--;
                lblMumberOfFiles.Content = urlsCounter;

                if (e.UserState.ToString().Contains("Radar"))
                {
                    drawonimage.DrawText(datesonimages[0].ToString(), @"d:\Downloaded Images\Radar\radImage6.gif");
                }
            }
            
            if (extractOnce == false)
            {
                radar.GetRadarImages();
                await Task.Delay(5000);

                for (int i = 0; i < radar.links.Count; i++)
                {
                    urls.Add(radar.links[i]);
                }

                dates = radar.dates;
                foreach(var date in dates)
                {
                    datesonimages.Add(date.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyy HH':'mm"));
                }

                ExtractLinks();
                extractOnce = true;
            }
        }
```

In the OnDownloadFileComplete event I want to know what file have been downloaded fine without any errors and then do some manipulation/s on this image file.

When downloading the images at this method I know if the file is Radar or not :
But the manipulation I want to do for the images is when they are downloaded each "Radar" that have been success downloaded I want to do something with that image from the hard disk in the OnDownloadFileComplete event. I'm not sure how to find the "Radar" each downloaded image file in the OnDownloadFileComplete event.

```
int countRad = 0;
        int countSat = 0;
        private async Task DownloadAsync(WebClient Client)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < urls.Count; i++)
            {
                stopwatch.Start();

                string extractFile = textBoxSatelliteFolder.Text + "\\extractFile.txt";
                string fNameRad = textBoxRadarFolder.Text + "\\radImage" + countRad + ".gif";
                string fNameSat = textBoxSatelliteFolder.Text + "\\satImage" + countSat + ".gif";
                if (urls[i] == "https://myimage.com/")
                {
                    await Client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(urls[i]), extractFile);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (urls[i].Contains("Radar"))
                    {
                        await Client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(urls[i]), fNameRad);

                        countRad++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await Client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(urls[i]), fNameSat);

                        countSat++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't you know which file you start downloading?

Comment: @Andy not in the complete event. I know what file I'm downloading but I want to get the file name in the complete event.

Comment: Why can't you save the file name in a variable and read it in the completed event? If you load asynchronously you can await download and it'll have completed so you don't need the event.

Comment: Why do you need the DownloadFileCompleted event if you are awaiting the downloads?